# onTextChange target not called when text is changed with picker view - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have two text fields.

One is for person type: "Husband, "Wife", "Single", "Child".
The other is for birth order.

I want the birth order text field to be enabled only when the text of the person type text field is "Child".

The input view of the person type text field is a picker view with the 4 options. I've tried adding a target to my person type text field like so:

```
personTypeTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTextChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

Then the onTextChange function does this:

```
func onTextChange() {
    if personTypeTextField.text == "Child" {
        birthOrderTextField.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        birthOrderTextField.isEnabled = false
        birthOrderTextField.text = ""
    }
}
```

But the onTextChange function isn't called when I make a person type selection with the picker view. Why isn't it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below UIPickerView delgate method Instead of textField selector

**Responding to Row Selection**

> func pickerView(UIPickerView,didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)

Called by the picker view when the user selects a row in a component.

```
self.personTypeTextField.text = YOUR_ARRAY[row]
```

Finally check

```
if personTypeTextField.text == "Child" {
        birthOrderTextField.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        birthOrderTextField.isEnabled = false
        birthOrderTextField.text = ""
    }
```

Don't forget to assign delegate to pickerView.

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought to do that since I was already implementing the pickerView didSelectRow method to set the text of the text field. But you'd think a textField value changed function would still be called even if the value is changed with a picker view.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you dont type directly in the input view but rather choose an option from a picker view. I guess that you are assigning a new value to personTypeTextField.text programmatically. In that case, it's normal that the UIControlEvents.editingChanged target isn't called because the input view was never edited by the user. You should run your function when the picker has finished picking the value.